# Xcode Saving/loading data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, save, loading

I want to save some data for my application ... I have to save 3 strings and 3 integers

The way I am doing it doesn't seem ethical and gives error specially on iOS simulator

I am looking for a way that Apple will approve

Will the following code give error on first execution (e.g there is no file or something like that) (load data is called as soon as the app starts )

Here is my code

```
 - (NSString *) saveFilePath{
NSArray *path =
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
return [[path objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savefile.plist"];
 }



-(void)loadData:(int)a{
NSString *myPath = [self saveFilePath];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPath];    
if (fileExists) {        
    NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPath];        
    NSString *myString;
    myString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@`s : %@ Taps",[values objectAtIndex:(a++)],[values objectAtIndex:a]];
    label.text=myString;
    hscore=[[values objectAtIndex:a] integerValue];
}   
 }


-(void)saveData:(int)a{

NSArray *values=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"No Game",@"0",@"No Game",@"0",@"No Game",@"0", nil];

NSString *myPath = [self saveFilePath];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPath];
if (fileExists) {
    values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPath];
} 
 // some value changing logic that works 
 [values writeToFile:myPath atomically:YES];
 }
```

Comment: You need to look into Core Data to store. The way you are doing it will rely on memory to load the entire object stored. If it is just a small amount of data, then it should be fine, but if you need more complex query ability and performance, Core Data is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess something is wrong with my compiler

i made the whole xcode project again copying all the code ans xib files and it Now Works

Cheers and Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try hardcoded path and test where is wrong !

```
- (NSString *) saveFilePath
 {    
     NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/savefile.plist"];
     NSString *fullFilePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
     return fullFilePath;
 }
```

Comment: the first break point occur on loadData`s first line i.e "NSString *myPath = [self saveFilePath];  "    in output panel it says lldb and in auto panel it says variable is not a cfString ...